# Laravel: I can't insert datetime or timestamp inside mysql

Tags: laravel, datetime

I am trying to insert an string date-time format into database but it doesn't seem to be working. This is the time format:

```
 $created_at = "Fri Jun 30 09:38:29 +0000 2017";
```

And this is my Code:

```
 $tweet = \App\AdminModels\Tweet::updateOrCreate(
        ['twitter_id' => $result->id],
        ['pub_date' => $created_at,'text' => $text]
 );
```

The script successfully inserts/update a record but the 'pub_date' column remains zero depending on the data type I choose.

For example if I choose the datatype as timestamp and defalut NULL, it remains null.

If I select datetime as the datatype it remains: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you pub_date in your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql throw `Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column` error for your input `"Fri Jun 30 09:38:29 +0000 2017"`.

If the field type `timestamp`,the input value format should be `2017-06-30 03:35:31` like this format `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: Thanks. Marked as answer.  I actually tried that before but reading you answer found out that instead of Y-M-D H:i I had to change it to Y-m-d H:i;

Answer (score 1):

Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to parse the date for `datetime` datatype

```
$created_at = "Fri Jun 30 09:38:29 +0000 2017";


$tweet = \App\AdminModels\Tweet::updateOrCreate(
        ['twitter_id' => $result->id],
        [
            'pub_date' => Carbon::parse($created_at)->toDateTimeString(),
            'text' => $text
        ]
 );
```